# Why can't I create multiple paths with a for loop

Tags: swiftui

in this simple reproduced code I abstracted a problem that I was experiencing in a bigger project.

What I am trying to do is create a Rectangle (successful) and draw multiple ellipses, each one bigger than the last, inside of the Rectangle (failure). Below is code that is ready to be copied and pasted... What am I doing wrong?

*Updated code to fix unrelated issue*

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MyShape()
            .stroke()
            .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct MyShape: Shape {
    @State private var horizontalMultiplier: CGFloat = 0.5
    @State private var verticalMultiplier: CGFloat = 0.5
     func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
       
        var path = Path()
        path.addRect(rect)
        var newPath = Path()
        for _ in 0...5 {
            let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1 * horizontalMultiplier, y: 1 * verticalMultiplier)
            newPath.addEllipse(in: rect, transform: transform)
            path.addPath(newPath)
            horizontalMultiplier += 0.25
            verticalMultiplier += 0.25
        }
        return path
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the declarations of the variables you're trying increment *outside* your loop -- they're getting recreated (and thus stay `0`) each time right now.

*Update, after edit: there doesn't appear to be a reason to try to use `@State` here -- just define the variables within `path`. If you do need mutable state over time, store it in the parent view and pass it through via parameters*

```
struct MyShape: Shape {
     func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
       
        var path = Path()
        path.addRect(rect)
        var newPath = Path()
        
        var horizontalMultiplier: CGFloat = 0.5
        var verticalMultiplier: CGFloat = 0.5
        
        for _ in 0...5 {
            let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1 * horizontalMultiplier, y: 1 * verticalMultiplier)
            newPath.addEllipse(in: rect, transform: transform)
            path.addPath(newPath)
            horizontalMultiplier += 0.25
            verticalMultiplier += 0.25
        }
        return path
    }
}
```

Comment: Moved the vars and made them nonzero and now I am experiencing the unexpected behavior I had earlier .. I do not know why I cannot add multiple shapes.

Comment: @SergioBost I'll take a look. In general, I'm not a fan of answering a question accurately and then having the question changed to something new and then having the answer (that was correct for the original question) unaccepted. Your updated even says "Updated code to fix unrelated issue"

Comment: Understood, Not a slight to you, just proper organization of the forum. I wouldn't want someone to come to a post that has been 'answered' with something unexpected.

Comment: Right, which is probably why changing the original question to be a different issue to the first wasn't a good idea. Looking at your new code, I'm confused as to why you're using `@State` within the `Shape`. I'd assume `@State` only works for `View`s.

Comment: You’re right, I’ll create a new question, and it’s state because I can’t make the func mutating

Comment: Don't store `@State` in the `Shape` at all. Pass it in from a parent `View`. In my original answer, those variable definitions should still be within `func path`, just right above the `for` loop.

Comment: Got it to work, thanks for the assistance, and sorry for the induced headache 

Comment: @jnpdx nice pfp!

Comment: @aheze thanks! Hopefully getting back to real life again as the world opens up a bit.